# Using a text document file system, check operation not functioning?

Tags: php

Hi guy's i've got a simple system I'm using to keep a basic database of user's document data. I know this isn't the conventional method at all but I wanted to see if it would work. So far so good. However, I've stubbed upon an issue where my site is outputting the data in my echo tags as the correct statements to trigger my if command when the page is loaded but for some reason it doesn't change the information in the text documents. Anyone know what I might be missing here?

```
<?php
ob_clean();session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
header("Location: index.php");
}

if (isset($_GET['Username'])){  
    $Username = $_GET['Username'];
}

$myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/NoOfDocuments.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
$NoOfDocs = fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);

$myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment/Subscribed.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
$Subscribed = fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);

$myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/DOC1/Name.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
$DocName = fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);

$myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/DOC1/URL.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
$DocURL = fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);

if ($Subscribed == false){
    if ($NoOfDocs == 0){
        $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/NoOfDocuments.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
        fwrite($myFile, ($NoOfDocs +1));
        fclose($myFile);

        $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/DOC1/Name.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
        fwrite($myFile, 'Risk Assessment');
        fclose($myFile);

        $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/DOC1/URL.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
        fwrite($myFile, 'RiskAssessment.php');
        fclose($myFile);

        $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment/Subscribed.txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
        fwrite($myFile, 'true');
        fclose($myFile);
    }       
}

echo 'Logged in as = '.$Username.'<br>';
echo 'Document Subscribed = '.$Subscribed.'<br>';
echo 'Number of Documents Subscribed to = '.$NoOfDocs.'<br>';
echo 'This Document is Called = '.$DocName.'<br>';
echo 'This Document is Located at = '.$DocURL.'<br>';

?>
```

**EDIT 1.0**

This is the information that is outputted by my echo tags as requested:

```
Logged in as = Matt
Document Subscribed = false
Number of Documents Subscribed to = 0
This Document is Called = DOC1-NAME
This Document is Located at = DOC1-URL
```

**EDIT 1.1**

Using Barmar method, still getting the same results:

```
<?php
ob_clean();session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
header("Location: index.php");
}

if (isset($_GET['Username'])){  
    $Username = $_GET['Username'];
}

$NoOfDocs = file_get_contents("USERS/".$Username."/NoOfDocuments.txt") or exit("Can't read file!");
$Subscribed = file_get_contents("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment/Subscribed.txt") or exit("Can't read file!");

if ($Subscribed == 'false'){
    if ($NoOfDocs == 0){    
        file_put_contents("USERS/".$Username."/NoOfDocuments.txt", ($NoOfDocs +1)) or exit("Can't write file!");
        file_put_contents("USERS/".$Username."/DOC1/Name.txt", "Risk Assessment") or exit("Can't write file!");
        file_put_contents("USERS/".$Username."/DOC1/URL.txt", "RiskAssessment.php") or exit("Can't write file!");
        file_put_contents("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment/Subscribed.txt", "true") or exit("Can't write file!");
    }       
}
?>
```

Comment: FYI, you might want to look at the functions `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`. It does what your `fopen`, `fgets/fwrite`, and `fclose` do in one call.

Comment: Please add the output from the `echo` statements to the question.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for helping here, I've edited my post with the information that the echo outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Subscribed` is a string, not a boolean. `fgets()` only returns a boolean `false` if it gets an error (e.g. end-of-file). It should be:

```
if ($Subscribed == 'false') {
```

Also, if the files have newlines at the end of the lines, these will be returned by `fgets()`. You should trim this off:

```
if (trim($Subscribed) == 'false') {
```

BTW, since these files just have a single line, you can use `file_get_contents` to read it in one step:

```
$Subscribed = file_get_contents("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment/Subscribed.txt") or exit("Can't read file!");
```

and then write it back out with:

```
file_put_contents("USERS/".$Username."/RiskAssessment/Subscribed.txt", "true") or exit("Can't write file!");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help here by the way, I've made an second edit and it looks like it's still outputting the same results have I not changed it correctly to the way you've suggested?

Comment: Nothing, no output at all.

Comment: What's that `"r"` doing in the call to `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Must have missed that one, thanks for clocking it. I've now removed it but still no change.

Comment: If you're not getting any output, your script must be getting an error. Check your server log.

Comment: Odd, there's no errors showing up in the server log.

Comment: I just commented out both if statements so that when the page is loaded it will write to the documents and change the data anyway. Just to see if it was the if statements. and they still didn't change.

Comment: Something is killing the script before it ever gets there, since you're not seeing the `var_dump` output. Even if the variable is empty it should print `null`.

Comment: I've been tinkering in my server and managed to get it to run. However, it keeps printing "Can't read file!"

Comment: Which file is it getting the error on? Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` enabled so you see the error messages?

Comment: Take off the `or exit` from reading `NoofDocuments.txt`.  The string "0" is falsey, so it's treating it as failure.

Comment: Okay I've removed the `or exit` on `NoofDocuments.txt` and it is now running everything 100% working... After that absolute nightmare. Thanks so much for all your help, been a lifesaver.